# Placing more priority on the swiping of a table view cell over the pan gesture of a page view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My situation: I have a page view controller with three table views as its content view controllers. These table view controllers have swipable cells that allow the user to perform different actions (delete, edit, etc.). How can I still trigger the swipable cells without triggering the page view controller scroll action? Or, rather, how do I set priority to the pan gesture on the table view cells over that of the page view controller?

Comment: Anybody have an idea that works?